# Would "on est les misérables" be grammatical and idiomatic?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

I would like to say something like, *nous sommes les misérables*, but I'm aware that the pronoun *nous* is rarely used in Francophone countries, or at least in France.

If I wanted to use the pronoun *on* instead, would it make sense to say *on est les misérables*? Would this sound natural to a French speaker?

Comment: My 1st thought is "it depends on the context". Can you elaborate a bit on how and where you would use that sentence ? Note that "nous" is not really "rarely" used: it is often replaced by "on" in informal, everyday spoken French, but is still common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ***on est les misérables*** is [perfectly grammatical](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#59_strong-em-on-nous-vous-accord-em-strong) in spoken French where ***on*** has almost completely superseded ***nous*** as a subject.

Speaking about *les misérables*, Victor Hugo, *Les Misérables* author who isn't especially known to use "improper French", "low French" or for being a football fan (Sorry @CédricVanRompay, I couldn't resist ;-) ) wrote these verses in his *[Alsace et Lorraine](http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/verlaine/index.php?navigation=textesauteurs&auteur=HUG_24&code_text=HUG1466)* poem 1872, *Toute la Lyre*:

> ...
>   Se ruant sur l'auguste et sombre genre humain.
>   **On est les chefs de l'ombre** et l'on a dans la main
>   Les rênes des chevaux du sépulcre, on excite
>   ...
>   On gonfle le flot noir des légions sinistres
>   **On est les dieux** ayant les démons pour ministres ;

However, in your sentence *les misérables* looks odd.

Perhaps did you want to say:

> ***on est misérables***
>   ***on est des miséreux***
>   ***on est dans la misère***

?

In any case, a famous phrase using the *on est les* pattern is ***On est les champions***.

A written, formal document will likely use ***nous sommes les ...*** though.

Answer (score 1):

The use of *on* in place of *nous* is considered as informal [1],
but in certain structures in just sounds weird,
and *"On est les [...]"* is one of them.
*"On est les misérables"* will not sound "incorrect" but just... "low French".

@jiliagre mentions *"On est les champions"* which is indeed a thing,
but it comes from a very specific context, namely football fans,
which is not considered as a reference for proper language.
Actually the fact that it "sounds a bit weird" might have help it becomes popular.

However it is interesting to note that *"On est + [adjective]"* is not considered as improper.

[1] There are other uses of *on* which are very formal: *"On voit clairement que ..."*, *"On retiendra que..."*